# Wordpress Post Transition - JS Alert

Tags: wordpress

We have a few processes that team member must follow when changing a Wordpress status. Because of this I am trying to display a message on status change as a reminder.

I found the post transition function on the WP Codex and think this is the right function for the job, I tried setting up simple JS Alert as a test but does not seem to work. I tested my function was being called using a die() test.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, does not need to be JS as long as I can display a message on status change..

My current function:

```
function status_change_dtp( $post  ) {
    echo "<script>alert('Display a message on change')</script>";
}
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'status_change_dtp', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: i guess the die() test was successful? What was the page like after the die? was is reloaded already? or not?

Comment: sorry yes the die() was successful. Not the die() seemed to happen  before reload

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution, rather than using the post transition hook I simply updated the status messages themselves...

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'rw_post_updated_messages' );

function rw_post_updated_messages( $messages ) {

    $post             = get_post();
    $post_type        = get_post_type( $post );
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    $messages['cpt_operator'] = array(
        6  => __( "Operator Published - <script>alert('Please Set to Live in Protostar')</script>." ),
        10 => __( 'Draft Saved.' )
    );

    return $messages;
}
```